# Joint Distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d random variables.  What conditions are necessary for $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $X+Y$ to be independent?

This holds in the case when $X,Y \sim \Gamma\left(a,b\right)$, but I'm not sure how to go about analyzing a general case.  Some basic simulation seems to show that it doesn't hold for normals, but is not rejected by copula-based tests of independence for the Beta distribution.

Comment: Are you assuming these are positive?

Comment: I hadn't initially, which is why I tried normals, but if that's a useful condition that would be interesting to know.

Comment: For the moment I will assume that $\Pr(X>0)=1$ and the distribution is absolutely continuous, so it is $f(x)\, dx$ on the interval $x>0,$ and that $f$ is smooth enough for the argument below to work. But I suspect one can prove that this whole thing is impossible for discrete distributions.

The joint distribution is then $f(x)f(y) \, dx\,dy$ on the quadrant $x>0,\,y>0.$

Let $u = \dfrac x {x+y}$ and $v=x+y,$ so that $x=uv$ and $y=(1-u)v.$ Then$\,\ldots\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $$
\left| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right| = v, \text{ and so } dx\,dy = v\,du\,dv.
$$
And then:
$$
f(x)f(y)\,dy\,dx = f(uv)f((1-u)v)\, v\,du\,dv.
$$
Thus we need functions $g$ and $h$ such that
$$
f(uv)f((1-u)v) \cdot v = g(u) h(v)
$$
or
$$
f(x)f(y)(x+y) = g\left( \frac x {x+y} \right) h(x+y).
$$

Comment: My suspicion is that $X,Y$ need to be independent Gamma-distributed random variables with the same scale parameter, but possibly different shape parameters.

Comment: The result certainly holds in that case.  Given that the distribution must satisfy a kind of "fat tail" property in which a large realization of $v$ isn't more informative regarding whether $x$ had a low realization or $y$ had a high realization, it does seem unlikely that other distributions satisfy, but that is why I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial solution which makes the following trong assumptions:

> **Assumption.** The common distribution of $X$ and $Y$ has p.d.f. $f$ which is supported on $(0, \infty)$ and satisfies $f(x) \sim c x^{\alpha}$ for some $c > 0$ and $\alpha \geq 0$ as $x\downarrow 0$.

Under this assumption, we can check that both $X$ and $Y$ have the gamma distribution.

Indeed, it is easy to check that $U = X+Y$ and $V = \frac{X}{X+Y}$ have densities $f_U$ and $f_V$, respectively, and for each $u > 0$ and $v \in (0, 1)$ the followings are true:

$$ f_U(u) = \int_{0}^{u} f(x)f(u-x) \, dx, \qquad u f(uv)f(u(1-v)) = f_U(u)f_V(v). $$

From this, we find that

$$ f_V(v) = \frac{f(uv)f(u(1-v))}{\int_{0}^{1} f(ux)f(u(1-x)) \, dx}. $$

Then dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $u^{2\alpha}$ and letting $u \downarrow 0$ gives

$$ f_V(v) = \frac{v^{\alpha}(1-v)^{\alpha}}{\int_{0}^{1} x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\alpha} \, dx} = Cv^{\alpha}(1-v)^{\alpha} $$

for the normalizing constant $C = \frac{\Gamma(2\alpha+2)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)^2}$. Plugging this back and writing $(x, y) = (uv, u(1-v))$,

$$ f(x)f(y) = C f_U(x+y) \frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}}{(x+y)^{2\alpha+1}}. $$

Dividing both sides by $y^{\alpha}$ and letting $y \downarrow 0$, we obtain $ Cf_U(x) = c x^{\alpha+1} f(x)$. So, if we define $g(x)$ by $f(x) = cx^{\alpha}g(x)$, then $g$ satisfies the functional equation

$$ g(x)g(y) = g(x+y) $$

and therefore $g(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda > 0$. Therefore it follows that both $X$ and $Y$ have the gamma distribution of rate $\lambda$ and shape parameter $\alpha+1$.