# Are $U=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $V=X+Y$ independent if $X$ and $Y$ are?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Under what conditions, $ U=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $V=X+Y$ are independent?

Notes:

1- Of course if you have independent $X,Y\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, $0\leq U\leq 1$ and $0\leq V\leq 2$, but $U$ and $V$ are not independent, e.g. $V=2$ implies $U=\frac{1}{2}$. So we may restrict our attention to independent unbounded random variables $X, Y$. (Maybe even positive r.v.s so that $X+Y$ will be non-zero.

2- I think when $X$ and $Y$ are unbounded, then scaling both of them with same constant keeps $U$ unchanged, but we can make $V$ as large or small as possible by varying that constant. So it seems given $U$, we don't have any information about $V$.

3- Today in our stat class we showed that for independent $X\sim \text{Gamma}\left(\alpha_1,\beta\right)$ and $Y\sim \text{Gamma}\left(\alpha_2,\beta\right)$, joint pdf $f_{_{U,V}}\left(u,v\right)$ decomposes into product of marginal pdfs of $U\sim \text{Beta}\left(\alpha_1,\alpha_2\right)$ and $V\sim \text{Gamma}\left(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\beta\right)$, hence they are independent. That's where I started to think if there is a general result.

Comment: The same question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490119/joint-distribution-of-fracxxy-and-xy).

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for bringing it to my attention, but the answer for that question assumes $X$ and $Y$ to be i.i.d. and it uses a strong assumption about pdf near zero to conclude that $U$ and $V$ can be independent only when $X$ and $Y$ are Gamma distributed with different parameters $\alpha$. I'm looking for a general answer without any assumptions, except independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Your question was *Under what conditions*... If you do not like the conditions of being i.i.d. plus pdf's behaviour near zero then pose the question appropriately. Right now it is not clear. Do you want to prove  independence without any assumptions on $X$ and $Y$? Another point is that the similar question did not attract more general answers, what makes you believe that yours will do?

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes as I said in notes, I am looking for a general result without any more assumptions on $X$ and $Y$. BTW, It is my first time to ask a question in stackexchange and I don't want to attract attention! That similar question got that 1 answer accepted by owner and maybe that's why it did not attract more attention.